# Azure bot service creator not giving me QnA template

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I've been having issue with trying to create a bot service on the Microsoft Azure package. What I aim to do is link up my QnA bot with the azure bot service so that I can link a web app up to my website.

I have already created the QnA bot and everything seems perfectly fine from that part of the process. Now the next step would be to create a service from the Microsoft Azure Web App bot. I have watched some youtube videos and have done extensive research on the net about how to create this service, but none of them have the same interface that I am receiving? Basically it doesn't give me the option to select the Question and Answer template (which I need so that I can link up the QnA bot service).

Am I missing a step? Are there other ways to link up the Bot using Azure? Please let me know as I'm under a time constraint for this feature to be delivered. I will try and edit this later on with photos if you require them for extra assistance

Comment: It would be good to provide more context for your question. As it stands you are not proving enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QnA Template is currently hidden; it'll be back very soon.  We had a slight hiccup with it when deploying and wanted to make sure it was right before everyone started creating bots with it again.

Comment: Okay It seems like it has been resolved now. I had to add the keys through some hard coding and that seemed to work fine but thanks anyway.

Comment: The QnA Template seems to be hidden again?